# How to test email notification to the Administrator?

Tags: apex, unit-test, email, user, singleemailmessage

I can't insert right profile to test user like an administrator and don't know how to test it right. Help me please.

```
public void notifyAdministrator(String errorException){
    User user = [SELECT Email FROM User WHERE Profile.Name = 'System Administrator'];
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> allMails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    message.toAddresses = new String[] { user.Email };
    message.subject = 'The operation failed';
    message.setSaveAsActivity(false);
    message.plainTextBody = errorException; 
    allMails.add(message);
    Messaging.sendEmail(allMails); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must know which profile your company (IT Team/SFDC admin) uses for Admin user. Sometimes people use standard one (that you have mentioned) and sometimes they create custom profile...it's purely organization based thing ...not a generic...

But still if you want to query an admin user then you can replace your query to with below one...(Admin - based on fact that admin is user having at least 'Customize Application' permission).

```
User usr = [select id, email from user where profile.PermissionsCustomizeApplication= true and isActive=true limit 1];
```